# Fiber product and $G$-invariant maps

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $S^n \times_{\mathbb{Z}_2} \mathbb{R}$ be the fiber product of unitary sphere $S^n$ and $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Z}_2$, where $\mathbb{Z}_2$ acts on $S^n$ by antipodal relation and on $\mathbb{R}$ by sign rapresentation. If $Hom_{\mathbb{Z}_2}(S^n,\mathbb{R})$ is the set of $\mathbb{Z}_2$-invariant maps and $\Gamma(S^n \times_{\mathbb{Z}_2} \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^n)$ the set of cross-section of the bundle $S^n \times_{\mathbb{Z}_2} \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^n$, I have to prove that there is a 1-to1 map 
$$ \phi: Hom_{\mathbb{Z}_2}(S^n,\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \Gamma(S^n \times_{\mathbb{Z}_2} \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^n) $$
In order to do this I have to prove that $ Hom_{\mathbb{Z}_2}(S^n,\mathbb{R}) = S^n \times_{\mathbb{Z}_2} \mathbb{R} $. How can I prove it?

Comment: What do you mean by $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}_2}(S^n, \mathbb{R}) = S^n\times_{\mathbb{Z}_2} \mathbb{R}$?  One is a group and the other is a topological space.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: Both of these are spaces... the space of equivariant maps, and the quotient of $S^n \times \mathbb{R}$ by the diagonal action of $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: Don't use the "geometry" tag for questions like this. If you look at the other questions that have this tag you'll see that it doesn't fit.